# Transcribe replace returning weird string

Tags: templates, transcribe, multi-language, language, multilingual

It's my first time with EE and I'm modifying the template of an existing blog. It's multilingual so it uses code like `{exp:transcribe:replace name='written_by'}` to display different texts, in this case, `Written by`.

On some pages, for example on an article single, this line of code returns `Written by` as it should.

However, on some pages, for example on the index, it returns `M10O93H7PQ09L8X1T49CHY01Z5J4TT91FGFR`...

Sample returned HTML code:

```
<a href="M00o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfrthe-real-url-appears-here">
    <img src="http://www.website.com/images/image.jpg" />
    <h3>Article title</h3>
</a>

<p>
    M10o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfr <a href="/author/jdoe" class="author">Jhon Doe</a>
    M20o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfr <span>Feb 25, 2015</span>
</p>
```

Template code:

```
{exp:channel:categories show_empty="yes" channel="my_channel" id="categorylist" category_group="11" style="linear"}

    <h1>{category_name}</h1>

    {exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" category="{category_id}" limit="3" paginate="bottom"}
        <a href="{exp:transcribe:uri path='/article/'}{url_title}">
            {blog_post_main_image}
                <img src="{path}/{filename}.{extension}" />
            {/blog_post_main_image}
            <h3>{title}</h3>
        </a>

        <p>
            {exp:transcribe:replace name='written_by'} <a href="/author/{username}" class="author">{author}</a>
            {exp:transcribe:replace name='on_date'} <span>{entry_date format="%M %d, %Y"}</span>
        </p>
    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Any idea why it does that? I tried to search a lot on Google and found nothing that could help me.

Thanks!

Comment: it's to do with parse order. something is mixed up.Can you try addin a parse="inward" to the exp:channel:entries tag?

Comment: @JelleDijkstra thanks a lot for your answer. When I add ```parse="inward"``` to the ```exp:channel:entries``` there is no change, the bug is still here. BUT when I replace ```{exp:transcribe:replace name='written_by'}``` to ```{exp:transcribe:replace parse="inward" name='written_by'}``` it works just fine!! Is there a way to make this change global so I don't have to add this line everywhere? I'll do some research on my own but if you think at something let me know!! THANKS again! **I edited the template code in the question to include more code, I should have done that first.**

Comment: You are doing something else what seems a bit tricky too: you are nesting a channel entries tag within a channel:categories tag. I guess that's also causing the problem. It would be best to pass the category_id to an embed where the channel:entries is in

Comment: Thanks for your help. You should add an answer about ```parse="inward"``` so I can mark it as accepted as it helped a lot.

Comment: Incidentally, how does EE come up with such "random" strings? I ask because I got the _exact_ same string on a site I'm developing, which tells me it's not exactly random...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's to do with parse order. something is mixed up.Can you try addin a parse="inward" to the exp:channel:entries or the exp:transcribe:replace tag?